# Django. Does not removes files when upload new one

Tags: django

Django does not deletes old file when new one is uploading. Instead of it adds `'_'` to the a new file name and keep old file in the storage. How it can be solved?

Comment: It can't he "solved".  It's a feature.  It's part of Django.  That's the way it works.

Comment: No, he is not joking, [get-available-name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/#get-available-name-name)

Comment: Pol, you need to realize that more then one process running Django can be asked to upload files with same name at the same time, and Django has to somehow work around this problem.

Comment: So there is no way to delete the file?

Comment: @Pol: "So there is no way to delete the file?"  That's a completely different question.  Do you want to delete the file?  That's trivial.  Perhaps you should ask that as a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your question is not your real question.

First, your title is just a complaint.  You might want to fix that.

Second, "How it can be solved?" is a terrible question, since it isn't a "problem" that needs a "solution".  It's a feature of the field.

Third, in a comment (not the question) you ask this ("So there is no way to delete the file? "), which is perhaps worse than both other questions.

The answer is "no".  It's not true that there's no way to delete the file.

(Hint, avoid negative questions.)

My preference is to leave it at that.  The answer is "No".  Please ask better questions.

But, I'll provide a hint as to what I'm guessing your real question is.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FieldFile.delete

Comment: S.Lott, sorry! it's because of my poor English.  I really appreciate all you help.  But sometime composing of sentences can take from me a lot of time. If it offends you, i gonna correct the topic. Thanks!

Comment: @Pol: It's not your English.  It's the goal for your question.  Have a more clear goal in mind.  Say to yourself: "I want to do [X]" first.  Then change this to a question: "How do I do [X]?"  If you want to remove the old file, say this first: "I want to remove the old file."  Then make this into a question.

Comment: Ok! I agree whit you! It's really most terrible question I ever ask about django :).. Looks like complain. I did not want to complaine.

Answer (score 1):

I will agree with the comments that this is a feature and not a bug but I will point out that there was a ticket opened (and later closed as wontfix) against Django that might be helpful if you would like to try to "fix" this. See http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11663 for a patch and additional comments/guidance.